# Display octal value without being interpreted with tr?

Tags: scripting, sh

I have

```
./script "test\42"
```

Here is an example script :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "$1"
```

It gives me :

```
test" (42 being interpreted as an ASCII octal value, 42 = ")
```

How can I do to display

```
test\42 (instead test" ?)
```

With the help of tr (translate Unix command)?

Comment: May i know what the tr tag represents? I tried the tag wiki on SO to no avail.

Comment: Probably the tr (translate) unix program.  http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/tr.shtml

Comment: I can't reproduce this with bash or csh under Linux.  What shell and OS are you using?  Is there more to the script than echoing the argument value?

Comment: Yep it's the tr Unix command. I forgot to say that is a bourne shell script (sh instead bash). Apparently with bash it escapes the caracter but not in sh.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either using single quotes:

```
./script 'test\42'
```

or escaping the slash:

```
./script "test\\42"
```

Comment: It gives me the same result with simple quotes. The problem is that I can't escape the slash :/

Comment: Even if you use single quotes inside the script (in the 'echo' line?)

Comment: If I put echo '$1' the variable is not interpreted